# How to display "no result(s) found" using searchview in android

Tags: android, searchview

Here is my code in "`if (cursor == null)`." As you can see, I don't put any code there because I don't know how to display "no result(s) found" in the ListView if the user doesn't match his input to the searchview. I'm using ListView to display the search results of the user.

```
Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.searchCrvJapanesealpha((query != null ? query.toString() : "@@@@"));
if (cursor == null) {

} else {

    // Specify the columns we want to display in the result 
    String[] from = new String[] {
        DBAdapter.KEY_JAPANESECHAR,
        DBAdapter.KEY_JAPANESEALPHA};
```

I'm just beginner with Android.

Comment: how about a Toast-Message at this point? At least it was made for this kind of alerts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one `TextView` with text "**no result(s) found**" after listview. Now defalut visibility of `TextView` is gone. Now if condition is true set visibility of `TextView` to true and listview to gone.

Answer (score 0):

read about empty view, for example: http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/06/20/listview-tips-tricks-1-handle-emptiness/